# Jenkins - How to get properties/fields of choice param defined in shared lib

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have defined set of choice parameters in our shared Jenkins library, and I have a job in which I want to be able to create a set of permutations of some of them. e.g.:
in shared `dynamic_params.groovy`:

```
def dev_team() {
    def teams = ['backend', 'frontend']
    return choice(name: 'team', description: 'Choose the name of the team', choices: teams)
}

def environment() {
    def environments = ['prod', 'qa', 'staging']
    return choice(name: 'environment', description: 'Choose an environment', choices: environments)
}
```

Then, all I wanna do is, in a job, something like:

```
def envTeams = [:]

for (env in dynamic_params.environment().choices) {
    for (team in dynamic_params.dev_team().choices) {
        envTeams[env] = team
    }
}
......
```

(examples are mocked)

But I get `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field`

I'm not even yet sure what do I get when I do `dynamic_params.environment()` because Jenkins prints
`@choice(name=environment,description=Choose an environment,choices=[prod, qa, staging])`
(Does that mean I have a class?)

Thanks

Comment: Your methods are returning `choice`. These methods have no members, so your invocation namespace should be merealy `dynamic_params.environment()`. That will return the choice object, and you can parse it from there.

Answer (score 1):

By your choice of `choice` (pardon the pun) I understand that you want to populate a parameter of the job before presenting it to the user in e.g. "Build with parameters" page.

That is a common trap: you want to run some code to prepare a parameter, but in order to execute your code Jenkins needs to run your pipeline, which happens after "Build with parameters" is pressed.

You have two options: either use ActiveChoice plugin, or run a scripted pipeline before your main pipeline. In your case this may look like this:

```
my_choice = ''

node('master') {
    stage('prepare choices') {
        println "before: my_choice is ${my_choice}"
        my_choice = get_choices() // def get_choices() { return ['prod', 'qa', 'staging'] }
        println "after: my_choice is ${my_choice}"
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters { choice(name: 'CHOICES', choices: my_choice, description: '') }

    // rest of pipeline
```

Comment: That's not the issue.
The actual issue is that I don't have a `get_choices()` method, nor do I want to create one. I'm pretty convinced this class (or struct or whatever) which is choice, is supposed to have it already (i.e. in my example: `environment().get_choices()` ??)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your issue then :)